# Display selected value from listbox (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have database, which consists of table "Jobs": job_id (int, primary key), job_nm (nchar(50)).
In "Model" folder I add ADO.NET Entity data model.

Controller is:

```
namespace ListBox_proj.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        myDBEntities1 db = new myDBEntities1();

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()`enter code here`
        {
            var jobs = db.Jobs;

            ViewBag.Jobs = jobs;                    

            return View(jobs);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string sel1)
        {
            ViewBag.Result = sel1;

            return View();
        }       

    }
}
```

View is:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<html>
    <head>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
        <title>Index</title>        

    </head>

    <body>
            <h1 class="label">Please, select the job you interested in:</h1> <br /><br />

            <select name="sel1" id ="sel1">
                <option>All</option>
                @foreach (var j in ViewBag.Jobs)
                {
                    <option><p>@j.job_nm</p></option>
                }
            </select> 

        <form action="/home/index" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value ="Search">        
            <input type="text">@ViewBag.Result</input>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

but when I choose the item in selectbox, and push "Search", I have error message:

![enter image description here][1]

MESSAGE IN ENGLISH - **Object reference not set to an instance of the object.**

Please, help me! What I do wrong?
How Can I correct it?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `ViewBag` when you are sending the jobs as a Model to the View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues here.

The first is that `ViewBag.Jobs` is only being populated on the `[HttpGet]`; you will need to ensure that the `ViewBag` is also populated in `[HttpPost]`. A better solution generally would be to use a proper view model - for example,

```
public class JobViewModel {
    public Jobs JobsList { get; set; }
    public string Result { get; set; }
}
```

Simply populate that in both the `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]` procedures, and pass it into the `View()` call. Then add:

```
@model JobsViewModel
```

at the top of the view to allow you to access it through the (strongly-typed) `Model.JobsList` property.

A secondary issue that you'll come across is that `sel` isn't being submitted, as it falls outside of your `<form>` tags - remember, the only information submitted in a form is that contained within it.

Restructure your view to:

```
    <form action="/home/index" method="post">
        <select name="sel1" id ="sel1">
            <option>All</option>
            @foreach (var j in Model.JobsList)
            {
                <option><p>@j.job_nm</p></option>
            }
        </select>

        <input type="submit" value ="Search">        
        <input type="text">@Model.Result</input>
    </form>
```

and that problem should also be solved.